# How can I add href to Icon for Ant Design?

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

How can I add an Url link to the icon?

---

```
  <Space>
       <a href={team.github}>
          <GithubOutlined className="teamSocialIcon" />
       </a>
       <a href={team.linkedin}>
          <LinkedinFilled className="teamSocialIcon" />
       </a>
    </Space>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Button component of Ant Design and change the type to "text" or "link".

```
<Button type="text" href={team.github}>
  <GithubOutlined className="teamSocialIcon" />
</Button>
```

or

```
<Button type="text" href={team.github} icon={<GithubOutlined className="teamSocialIcon" />} />
```

But I usually create a component with these two combined to add more custom functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Button component of Ant Design and change the type to "link".

```
<Button type="link" href="url://" icon={<Your Icon/>} />
```